generate SignedJWT via org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtGenerator, Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds' accessible;
while upgrading to pac4j 6.1, the below exception is thrown while trying
to generate signed JWT
2024-11-27 12:08:01 SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-18] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
        com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.time.Instant#seconds' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#reflection-inaccessible
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:76)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:388)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:628)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:57)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:154)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:944)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:899)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:848)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:825)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.util.JSONObjectUtils.toJSONString(JSONObjectUtils.java:545)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toString(Payload.java:363)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toBytes(Payload.java:395)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.Payload.toBase64URL(Payload.java:412)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.composeSigningInput(JWSObject.java:193)
                at com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.<init>(JWSObject.java:112)
                at com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT.<init>(SignedJWT.java:60)
                at org.pac4j.jwt.config.signature.RSASignatureConfiguration.sign(RSASignatureConfiguration.java:89)
                at org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtGenerator.internalGenerate(JwtGenerator.java:109)
                at org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtGenerator.generate(JwtGenerator.java:82)
                at com.bmc.ctmem.idpvalve.helper.JwtGeneratorHelper.generate(JwtGeneratorHelper.java:71)


thanks,
Eyal

adding --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED to the JVM parameters resolved the issue, however since my code is running as a valve in TOMCAT I am not sure if is a valid resolution
